# Selecting cell when values match

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

The code below finds whatever value I input in "K2" in sheet 1 and then it looks for the same value in sheet 2. I would like that when it finds a match, to select that specific cell. Can someone help me with that?

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rSearchRng As Range
    Dim EndNum As Long
    Dim vFindVar As Variant`

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    EndNum = WS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Set rSearchRng = WS.Range("A1:A" & CStr(EndNum))
    Set vFindVar = rSearchRng.Find(Range("K2").Value)
    If Not vFindVar Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Match"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Match Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim EndNum As Long
Dim vFindVar As Variant`
Dim wsOrig as worksheet

Set wsOrig as activesheet
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

EndNum = WS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set rSearchRng = WS.Range("A1:A" & CStr(EndNum))
Set vFindVar = rSearchRng.Find(wsOrig.Range("K2").Value)
If Not vFindVar Is Nothing Then
    'to select a cell the sheet must be active
    WS.Activate
    vFindVar.Select
Else
    MsgBox "No Match Found"
End If

End Sub
```